# Rails: writing a record asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency

in my Rails 5 RC1 app write some log entries into a DB table through an ActiveRecord model.
Writing this log entry takes a couple of milliseconds and delays the response for the end user. 
I am searching for a mechanism how I can execute the log-writing into the "background" so it is not blocking/delaying the response (kind of "fire-and-forget"). Do you have some hints on how to do that?

I tried to wrap the respective part into

```
Thread.new { code }
```

But this even seems to further delay the response a few MS.

I appreciate any hint!

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into messaging services like RabbitMQ for asynchronous transactions and activities. I use RabbitMQ in exactly the way you describe.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I already did think about that. But I was hoping to find a solution that does not require additional installations on the server...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActiveJob, you could use `:async`, which looks to be the default `queue_adapter` for ActiveJob. However, this doesn't persist jobs between restarts and is not really recommended for production.

See [Rails 5 changed Active Job default adapter from Inline to Async](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/29/rails-5-changed-default-active-job-adapter-to-async.html).